# Play Framework 1.2.4: Session Doesnt Change

Tags: session, playframework, playframework-1.x, securesocial

I am working on a Play Framework project and I am using `SecureSocial` plugin for user actions.

My problem is, according to Play Framework document, the session should have been closed and reset when I closed the browser tab and opened a new tab.

But when I close and reopen the tab, I see that the session id is still the same and user logs in directly without reopening the login page (because user info is still available on play session)

Here's the output from before and after I open a session:

### Before

```
session = {sid=86, ___ID=80519f26-ccf9-4e6f-9f9a-0f2a3bbc7b20, securesocial.network=userpass, ___AT=4241355a05e419dabc6e16612275b3d932133707, securesocial.user=test}
```

And then I close and reopen the browser tab after a few seconds...

### After

```
session = {___ID=80519f26-ccf9-4e6f-9f9a-0f2a3bbc7b20, sid=86, securesocial.network=userpass, ___AT=4241355a05e419dabc6e16612275b3d932133707, securesocial.user=test}
```

everything is the same. **Sometimes it changes randomly**.

By the way, I don't have any session settings in `application.conf` or anywhere else; everything is still in its default setting.

Comment: I was under the impression that socialsecure uses cookies - it checks if the user has been authenticated previously.  So unless you go ahead the delete the cookies, it should not start from the beginning (for validation)

Comment: I think inside SocialSecure.java: checkAccess is called - which calls getUserId (where the cookies are checked for user & provider)

Comment: yes ali,inside SocialSecure.java the cookies are being called from the session with sessin.get(...). The problem is the session doesnt change as its supposed to be.

Comment: perhaps I misunderstood your question - will check again

Comment: just for my benefit - which browser and provider is this?

Comment: i am using google chrome browser in osx but the problem persists in other platforms and browsers too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've realized that this is a new "feature" on modern browsers. Unless you fully close all tabs and the browser itself entirely (in osx, right click and close), the browser wont close the session, so the user doesnt nee dto relog until they completely close the browser..

So in short, your session will not expire with just closing the "tab", but you have to close the "browser" entirely.

Answer (score 1):

SocialSecure uses cookies - it checks if the user has been authenticated against a certain provider before.  Deleting the cookies should allow you to test the functionality from the beginning.

Inside SecureSocial.java (in controllers.securesocial) - you should be able to check where inside checkAccess, getUserId is called (where it checks the cookie values for the user and provider).

Hope it helps

Comment: i've seen those lines, the problem is, the session shuold have been reset and session.get(...) shuld return null after i close and reopen the browser windows. But in my case, that doesnt happen.